# Layout issue: dialog containing ExpandableListView

Tags: android, dialog, expandablelistview

Here follows the code for my dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/source_select_public"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/source_select_public" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/source_select_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/source_select_commands"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/source_select_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/source_select_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@android:string/ok" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When the ExpandableListView is open, it is automatically scrollable; however, the two buttons below it disappear. I have tried enclosing the whole layout within a ScrollView, but then the scrollable behavior of the ExpandableListView is broken (i.e. it gets too small to be actually touched). What I would like to achieve is a dialog that can take up all the screen while allowing the ExpandableListView to be the only scrollable component. Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this can be achieved using a relative layout as the root layout instead of a linear layout